# minimal install CentOS6.6 network configuration (updated)

Tags: linux, centos, networking

I update my question.

I ask same question to stack overflow, but it is better to ask here.

I'm getting trouble with configuring my workstation network after minimal os installation. I edited `vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em1` for static. from the google search, I restart my network service again and again. but still can't connect to internet or ping(except `ping 127.0.0.1`). Here is my configurations.

```
[root@workstation ~]# uname -a
Linux workstation.XXXXX 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 15 04:27:16 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@workstation ~]# ifconfig
em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
          inet addr:aaa.bbb.ccc.xxx  Bcast:aaa.bbb.211.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: XXXX::XXXX:XXX:XXXX:XXXX/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:12465754 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:238 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1507354446 (1.4 GiB)  TX bytes:35268 (34.4 KiB)
          Interrupt:16

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:1316 (1.2 KiB)  TX bytes:1316 (1.2 KiB)

[root@workstation ~]# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: em1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet aaa.bbb.ccc.xxx/22 brd aaa.bbb.211.255 scope global em1
    inet6 XXXX::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: em2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

[root@workstation ~]# vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em1
DEVICE=em1
HWADDR=54:9F:35:1F:58:D0
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=7337edf4-f9f0-4dab-9d3d-6f031e7180cc
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=aaa.bbb.ccc.132
NETMASK=255.255.252.0
NAME="System em1"
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
PREFIX=22
GATEWAY=aaa.bbb.156.5
DNS1=aaa.bbb.10.2
DOMAIN=168.126.63.1

[root@workstation ~]# service network restart
Shutting down interface em1:                               [  OK  ]
Shutting down loopback interface:                          [  OK  ]
Bringing up loopback interface:                            [  OK  ]
Bringing up interface em1:  Determining if ip address aaa.bbb.208.132 is already in use for device em1...
                                                           [  OK  ]
[root@workstation ~]# yum list
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org'"
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base

[root@workstation ~]# vi /etc/sysconfig/network
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=workstation.XXXXX
GATEWAY=aaa.bbb.156.5
```

Thank you for your answer yes, @larsks em1 is static ip, not DHCP. Here is ip route

```
[root@workstation ~]# ip route
aaa.bbb.ccc.0/22 dev em1  proto kernel  scope link  src aaa.bbb.ccc.xxx
169.254.0.0/16 dev em1  scope link  metric 1002
```

Here is `vi /etc/resolv.conf`

```
[root@workstation ~]# vi /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver aaa.bbb.10.2
search 168.126.63.1
```

I change `NETWORK` to `GATEWAY`, but it is still can't connect to internet.

In addition, Great thanks for helping me.
I think, we are close to solution.

Comment: It looks like `em1` has an address, so your network configuration appears to be working.  What does your routing table look like?  Update your question with the output of `ip route`. Neither your `ifconfig-em1` file nor your `/etc/sysconfig/network` appears to define a default gateway.

Comment: @Jeff Schaller thanks for info me, i edit post. thanks

Comment: Can you show us the config file `ifcfg-em1` for more understanding. have you mentioned gateway any were. also show us the resolve.conf file.

Comment: @Mongrel Thank your for your comment, As I know, `NETWORK` is same as `GATEWAY`. I update `vi /etc/resolv.conf`. Thanks

Comment: `NETWORK` is not the same as `GATEWAY`.  As I said in my earlier comment, your problem is that you have no default route defined, and the output of `ip route` confirms that.  Update `ifcfg-em1` to specify a default gateway and things should work just fine.

Comment: @larsks Oh, I am sorry. It is a info from google. I edit this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solve the problem.

```
[root@workstation network-scripts]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
aaa.bbb.ccc.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 em1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 em1
```

It is not exist 'Default Gateway',

```
[root@workstation network-scripts]# ip route add 155.230.156.5 dev em1
[root@workstation network-scripts]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
aaa.bbb.156.5   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 em1
aaa.bbb.ccc.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 em1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 em1
```

And, next,

```
[root@workstation network-scripts]# route add default gw 155.230.156.5 dev em1
[root@workstation network-scripts]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
aaa.bbb.156.5   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 em1
aaa.bbb.ccc.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 em1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 em1
0.0.0.0         aaa.bbb.156.5   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 em1 ← "default GATEWAY"
```

Confirming connection,

```
[root@workstation network-scripts]# ping www.google.co.kr
PING www.google.co.kr (216.58.199.99) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from hkg07s22-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.199.99): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=82.8 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s22-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.199.99): icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=47.2 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s22-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.199.99): icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=46.9 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s22-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.199.99): icmp_seq=4 ttl=50 time=47.0 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s22-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.199.99): icmp_seq=5 ttl=50 time=57.3 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s22-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.199.99): icmp_seq=6 ttl=50 time=47.0 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s22-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.199.99): icmp_seq=7 ttl=50 time=47.6 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s22-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.199.99): icmp_seq=8 ttl=50 time=47.6 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s22-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.199.99): icmp_seq=9 ttl=50 time=46.9 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s22-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.199.99): icmp_seq=10 ttl=50 time=47.0 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s22-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.199.99): icmp_seq=11 ttl=50 time=47.5 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s22-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.199.99): icmp_seq=12 ttl=50 time=47.0 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s22-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.199.99): icmp_seq=13 ttl=50 time=47.5 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s22-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.199.99): icmp_seq=14 ttl=50 time=57.8 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s22-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.199.99): icmp_seq=15 ttl=50 time=47.5 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s22-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.199.99): icmp_seq=16 ttl=50 time=47.4 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s22-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.199.99): icmp_seq=17 ttl=50 time=53.0 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s22-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.199.99): icmp_seq=18 ttl=50 time=47.6 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s22-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.199.99): icmp_seq=19 ttl=50 time=47.5 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s22-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.199.99): icmp_seq=20 ttl=50 time=47.5 ms
64 bytes from hkg07s22-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.199.99): icmp_seq=21 ttl=50 time=47.0 ms
^C
--- www.google.co.kr ping statistics ---
21 packets transmitted, 21 received, 0% packet loss, time 20694ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 46.961/50.269/82.824/7.940 ms
```

But, when I `reboot` or `service network restart`, it restored.
Now I wonder how to save it permernant.

I got a little understanding about Linux Networking.
Thanks again for helping me.

Comment: route configuration save: `[root@workstation network-scripts]# vi route-em1` next type `155.230.156.5 dev em1` next line `default via 155.230.156.5 dev em1` save file. `service network restart` It work well.